# How bring div to front, resize and center it to the middle of the screen onclick in js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Please bear with me, I am having a hard time coming up with a good explanation for this.

So I want to make an info page where there are several divs that show a little preview of the information that it holds. Like this:
[standard view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l262.png)

And when a visitor clicks on one of the div's, it flips, increases in size and centers ontop of all the other div's without affecting them. Like this:

[when a div is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcC72.png)

So far I have accomplished the grid structure and the flip, but as soon as I begin to fiddle with the div's dimensions everything get's moved around:

https://jsfiddle.net/xdqwL807/

```js
    $(document).on("click", ".flip-container", function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('hover');
        $('.front').removeClass('front');
        $(this).toggleClass('zIndex')
    });
```

```css
.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000px;
}
.flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.bringToFront {
    width: 500px !important;
    height: 500px !important;
    align-content: center !important;
    z-index: 1000 !important;
}

.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
    display: inline-flex;
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
}
.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}
.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);

}

.green {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div style="display: flexbox; align-content: center; width: 100%; position:absolute"></div>
    <div class="flip-container">
        <div class="flipper">
            <div class="front">
                <!-- front content -->
                <div class="green">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <!-- back content -->
                <div class="blue">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-container">
        <div class="flipper">
            <div class="front">
                <!-- front content -->
                <div class="green">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <!-- back content -->
                <div class="blue">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>    
<script>
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include jsFiddle demo?

Comment: sorry, I edited the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use CSS position to achieve the desired result.
So here are the modifications I made to your code:

Added a wrapper `.card-holder` to each `.flip-container`, this is important to avoid shifting of the elements as `.flip-container` will have position fixed, so that other elements won't be shifted since `.card-holder` will be there to avoid shifting.

```html
<div class="card-holder">
  <div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <!-- front content -->
        <div class="green">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <!-- back content -->
        <div class="blue">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Added this CSS to the `.card-holder`

```css
.card-holder {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

and removed following from `.flip-container, .front, .back`

```css
.flip-container, .front, .back {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
}
```

Added following animation to the CSS, on focus animation the card will be fixed and will be 2x size and on blur it will be at its initial state.

```
.focus {
  animation: focus 0.4s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.blur {
  animation: blur 0.4s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes focus {
  to {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(2);
    z-index: 5;
  }
}

@keyframes blur {
  from {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(2);
    z-index: 5;
  }
}
  to {
    position: relative;
    top: initial;
    left: initial;
    transform: translate(0%, 0%) scale(1);
    z-index: 0;
  }
}
```

And here's the jquery code I added:

```js
if((!$(this).hasClass('focus') && !$(this).hasClass('blur')) || $(this).hasClass('blur')) {  
  // add focus and remove blur class for initial state as well as if blur class is available
  $(this).addClass('focus');
  $(this).removeClass('blur');
}
else if ($(this).hasClass('focus')) {
  // add blur and remove focus class if focus class is available
  $(this).addClass('blur');
  $(this).removeClass('focus');
}
// to stop event propagation to other elements
event.stopPropagation()
```

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/8jh4pwut/15/

```js
    $(document).on("click", ".flip-container", function (event) {
        $(this).toggleClass('hover');
        
        $('.front').removeClass('front');
        $(this).toggleClass('zIndex');
        if((!$(this).hasClass('focus') && !$(this).hasClass('blur')) || $(this).hasClass('blur')) {        
            $(this).addClass('focus');
            $(this).removeClass('blur');
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass('focus')) {
            $(this).addClass('blur');
            $(this).removeClass('focus');
        }
        event.stopPropagation()
    });
```

```css
.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000px;
}
.flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.bringToFront {
    width: 500px !important;
    height: 500px !important;
    align-content: center !important;
    z-index: 1000 !important;
}

.card-holder {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
    display: inline-flex;
}
.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}
.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);

}

.green {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
}

.focus {
  animation: focus 0.4s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.blur {
  animation: blur 0.4s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes focus {
  to {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(2);
    z-index: 5;
  }
}

@keyframes blur {
  from {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(2);
    z-index: 5;
  }
}
  to {
    position: relative;
    top: initial;
    left: initial;
    transform: translate(0%, 0%) scale(1);
    z-index: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="overlay">

</div>
    <div style="display: flexbox; align-content: center; width: 100%; position:absolute"></div>
    <div class="card-holder">
      <div class="flip-container">
          <div class="flipper">
              <div class="front">
                  <!-- front content -->
                  <div class="green">

                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="back">
                  <!-- back content -->
                  <div class="blue">

                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-holder">
      <div class="flip-container">
          <div class="flipper">
              <div class="front">
                  <!-- front content -->
                  <div class="green">

                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="back">
                  <!-- back content -->
                  <div class="blue">

                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>    
<script>
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and simplest way to do this, is using JavaScript. The explanation is below the code snippet.

```js
function hello() {
    document.getElementById('div').classList.add('anim'); 
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('div').classList.remove('anim');
    }, 1000); 
}
```

```css
#div{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.anim {
    animation: anim 1s;
}
@keyframes anim {
  to {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div" onclick="hello()"></div>
```

Now, in the **CSS** we have created our div, with some styles and we have created a **separate class**, with the animation style. Then as usual we add the keyframe rule to the animation.

Then in our **JS**, we have a function which adds that class to our div. Then we set a timeout function, which has the time specified to the length of the animation in milliseconds and this will remove the animation class from the div.

Then in the **HTML**, we specify `hello()` function as the `onclick` attribute of our div. That's it.

If you are interested in animations, you can visit my [blog](https://originalcodingcult.blogspot.com/), specifically [this one](https://originalcodingcult.blogspot.com/2020/11/CSS-animations-4.html) which talks about this technique only.